# How to set the logAnalyticsDestinationType property on an Azure Monitor Diagnostic Settings object?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure Monitor Diagnostic Settings object on which I am trying to set the `logAnalyticsDestinationType` property. But it does not stick:

```
~$ id=/subscriptions/4...d/resourceGroups/xyz/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/abc

~$ az monitor diagnostic-settings show --resource $id -n loganalytics-diagnostics --query logAnalyticsDestinationType

~$ az monitor diagnostic-settings update --resource $id -n loganalytics-diagnostics --set logAnalyticsDestinationType=AzureDiagnostics --query logAnalyticsDestinationType
"AzureDiagnostics"

~$ az monitor diagnostic-settings show --resource $id -n loganalytics-diagnostics --query logAnalyticsDestinationType

~$
```

Without delving into much details on why I want to set it, is it possible to set it at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's currently an open issue with Azure regarding this topic:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/20019
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/20140

It seems to be that there's an erratic behaviour where the `logAnalyticsDestinationType` property is not being set and it is returing as either:

- `null`
- `AzureDiagnostics`

Some responses on the first issue suggests that if you delete the Monitoring diagnostics settings and re-create it "fixes" in a non consistent way.

Although, I've had to delete it from the Portal UI and then re-create it through Terraform, and the `logAnalyticsDestinationType` was still set to null.

Comment: So I am not crazy. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update the **logAnalyticsDestinationType.** of azure monitor diagnostic settings with the Azure CLI command and was able to update it successfully like below:-

Azure CLI command:-

```bash
az monitor diagnostic-settings update --resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7/resourceGroups/siliconrg/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/siliconLA -n LAdiag --set logAnalyticsDestinationType=AzureDiagnostics
```

Output:-

[image]

Where **resource** is the **resource ID** of the Azure resource that you want to update the diagnostic settings of, the Resource Id can be found in the Properties tab of your Azure resource, and **-n** is the **name of the diagnostic settings** you want to update and **set** value is used to set the new property of **logAnalyticsDestinationType**.
**Make sure you use the correct resource ID in the $id variable, add the correct -n name and --set value to change the logAnalyticsDestinationType.**

**Reference:-**

[az monitor diagnostic-settings subscription | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/diagnostic-settings/subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-diagnostic-settings-subscription-update)

Comment: Could you run the get command, now that you set this property? Because my code snippets demonstrate that it is being **reported** as set, but when getting the object again, the property is not set.

Comment: @mark Unfortunately, It looks like an Issue on Azure's end, even I was not able to retrieve the value after being set, I even tried az rest command to get diagnostic settings, It is giving null. Command- az rest --method get --url https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/{name}?api-version=2021-05-01-preview